# Mapping nested list

Tags: java, mapstruct

I have a object with list of nested object

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class Notification {
    private Long id
    private Long statusId;
    private List <External> external;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class External{
    private Long externalId;
    private  LocalDate date;
}
```

Dto

```
@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class NotificationPayload {
    private Long id;
    private Long statusId;
    private List <ExternalReferencePayload> external;
}


@Getter
@Setter
@NoArgsConstructor
public class ExternalReferencePayload {
    private Long externalReferenceId;
}
```

Mapper

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface NotificationMapper{

  public Notification dtoToNotification(NotificationPayload  payload);
}
```

I search the way to map the nested list

Answer (score 0):

In order to perform custom mapping for certain elements it is only needed to define a mapping method and MapStruct will take care of the rest. In your example:

```
@Mapper(componentModel = "spring")
public interface NotificationMapper{

  public Notification dtoToNotification(NotificationPayload  payload);

  @Mapping(target = "externalId", source = "externalReferenceId")
  public External dtoExternal(ExternalReferencePayload payload);
}
```

With this the nested list will use the `dtoExternal` mapping method to perform the mapping. With `@Mapping` you control how the mapping between `externalId` and `externalReferenceId` should be done